# Нужна помощь telebot(python)! Хочу отправить файл doc ОПРЕДЕЛЁННОМУ пользователю или в группу! Не знаю как . Помогите пожалуйста

Tags: python, python-3.x, telebot, txt

```py
from calendar import weekday
from http import client
import telebot
from telebot import types
import os, signal, pickle, sys

bot = telebot.TeleBot('###############')

@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def user(message):
    sent = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Здравствуйте, введите своё полное имя (ФИО)?")
    bot.register_next_step_handler(sent, services)
    doc = open('client.txt', 'a')


@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def services(message):
    user_markup = telebot.types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(one_time_keyboard=True)
    user_markup.row('Записаться на курс')
    uslugi = bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "Какие услуги вас интересуют?", reply_markup=user_markup)
    bot.register_next_step_handler(uslugi, exp)
    doc = open('client.txt', 'a')
    doc.write("Имя заказчика - {name}\n".format(name=message.text))

def exp(message):
    exp_user = bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "Расскажите насколько хорошо вы знаете вб")
    bot.register_next_step_handler(exp_user, week_day)
    doc = open('client.txt', 'a')
    doc.write("Услуга - {exp_user}\n".format(exp_user=message.text))

def telephone(message):
    keyboard = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(one_time_keyboard=True)
    reg_button = types.KeyboardButton(text="Отправить номер телефона", request_contact=True)
    keyboard.add(reg_button)
    nomer = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Оставьте ваш контактный номер чтобы наш менеджер смог связаться с вами.', reply_markup=keyboard)
    bot.register_next_step_handler(nomer, save)
    doc = open('client.txt', 'a')
    doc.write("Выбранное время - {nomer}\n".format(nomer=message.text))

def week_day(message):
    user_markup1 = telebot.types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(one_time_keyboard=True)
    user_markup1.row('Среда', "Пятница")
    uslugi1 = bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "В какой день недели вы бы хотели провести курс?", reply_markup=user_markup1)
    bot.register_next_step_handler(uslugi1, time_user)
    doc = open('client.txt', 'a')
    doc.write("Знания - {uslugi1}\n".format(uslugi1=message.text))

def time_user(message):
    user_markup12 = telebot.types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(one_time_keyboard=True)
    user_markup12.row('16:00', '12:00')
    uslugi12 = bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "Выберите удобное вам время проведения курса?", reply_markup=user_markup12)
    bot.register_next_step_handler(uslugi12, telephone)
    doc = open('client.txt', 'a')
    doc.write("Выбранный день недели - {uslugi12}\n".format(uslugi12=message.text))

def save(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Спасибо за обращение. Мы свяжемся с вами в ближайшее время.')
    doc = open('client.txt', 'a')
    doc.write("Номер - {telephon}\n".format(telephon=message.contact.phone_number))
    doc.close()
    

       
def echo_all(message):
    bot.reply_to(message, 'Загрузка файла')
    doc = open('client.txt', 'rb')
    bot.send_document(message.chat.id, doc)#тут вместо message.chat.id я указывал свой id, #
#пробовал и message.chat.id, кстати лучше что бы бот отправлял документ в группу*
    doc.close()


    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```

Comment: Размер файла какой?

Comment: @Рамис 1КБ, в итоге может больше будет, примерно 10КБ